# How to query ContentType that is combination of Fields (Defined by "WithField")

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I've setted up a custom `ContentType` which is combined with other fields (such as `NumericField`). Now I want to create a query for this `ContentType` which requires applying some condition to one of combined fields.
in my code i have a `ContentPart` called `EstatePart` which contains a `NumericField` field named "`BedroomCount`" :

```
ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("EstatePart", part => part.Attachable()
        .WithField(
                "BedroomCount",
                fieldBuilder =>
                {
                    fieldBuilder.OfType(typeof(NumericField).Name);        
                })
```

Now how i can query from `EstatePart` by applying a condition to `BedroomCount` field?

This is what i've tried:

```
_contentManager.Query("Estate").Where<EstatePartRecord>(r=>r. // HERE I CAN'T ACCESS TO BEDROOMCOUNT FIELD
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I believe is the Fields are not part of the ...PartReccord.

I've managed to access a Media picker field in my model like this

```
public MediaPickerField MediaPicker
        {
            get
            {
                return (MediaPickerField)ContentItem.As<HeaderPart>().Fields.First(x => x.Name == "Image");
            }
        }
```

You should be able to get the fields of the Estate type > find the one named bedroom count and query agains that. ... sorry don't know the exact syntax

Comment: Thanks man I voted you, But in fact we should find a way to access to the ContentPart from its ContentRecord in .Where() extention method.